# Allow few URLs/Websites only on browser

Tags: browser-add-ons

I need like a browser to open ONLY a set of predefined URLs/Sites. I don't need remote management or anything like that,like Surefox but not commercial or cheaper for a few devices.

So, I want to block all sites except a few URLs

Comment: Something like a parental control that filters sites?

Comment: yes, but only allowing a few sites & by default all other site is blocked.